# Which approaches of quick adding of surroundings for text are exist in IntelliJ IDEA family IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea

### Basic example

Consider below code. I took [Pug preprocessor](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for example, but it could be any other declarative language like HTML, HAML, etc.

```
p.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
  dolore magna aliqua.
```

I need:

```
p.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, #[+ImprovedUnderline consectetur] adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
  dolore magna aliqua. #[+ImprovedUnderline ]
```

The content of last `#[+ImprovedUnderline ]` has not been inputted yet.

### Target

Provide 2 methods of **quick** adding of `#[+ImprovedUnderline TARGET_WORDS]` surrounding **without direct typing**:

1. Before `TARGET_WORDS` will be input.
2. After `TARGET_WORDS` will be input (select the `TARGET_WORDS` and surround it by `#[+ImprovedUnderline TARGET_WORDS]`).

### Why Live Templates can not handle it

Consider below Live template:

```
#[+ImprovedUnderline $SELECTION$]
```

For the version *2020.2*, if we have something in line and try to use above live template with `Ctrl + Alt + J`, all previous characters in line will be wrapped:

[image]

So the Live templates does not satisfy to first target.

Which other methods ItelliJ IDEA suggests?

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ IDEA makes it very easy to surround a code block with if, while, for and other statements or to make a code block become part of such statments as try/catch or synchronized. Simply select the code block to surround (don’t forget to use Ctrl + W to increase the current selection) and then press Ctrl + Alt + T (or right-click the selection and select Surround with… from the menu). IntelliJ IDEA will show a list of options to choose from

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The surrounding of pre-inputted code block (target #2) has been reached (with `Ctrl + Alt + J`). The problem is how to add the surrounding *before* input the code (by other words, surround the cursor, target #1). `Ctrl + Alt + T` can't do it same as `Ctrl + Alt + J` (the effect will be same as in my GIF animation in question field). How to reach the surrounding of cursor?